# Deep Learning: Dataset containing images of varying dimensions and orientations

Tags: dataset, deep-learning

This is a repost of the [question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/2403/dataset-containing-images-of-varying-dimensions-and-orientations) asked in ai.stackexchange. Since there is not much traction in that forum, I thought I might try my chances here.

I have a dataset of images of varying dimensions of a certain object. A few images of the object are also in varying orientations. The objective is to learn the features of the object (using Autoencoders).

Is it possible to create a network with layers that account for varying dimensions and orientations of the input image, or should I strictly consider a dataset containing images of uniform dimensions? What is the necessary criteria of an eligible dataset to be used for training a Deep Network in general.

The idea is, I want to avoid pre-processing my dataset by normalizing it via scaling, re-orienting operations etc. I would like my network to account for the variability in dimensions and orientations. Please point me to resources for the same.

**EDIT:**

As an example, consider a dataset consisting of images of bananas. They are of varying sizes, say, `265x525` px, `1200x1200` px, `165x520` px etc. 90% of the images display the banana in one orthogonal orientation (say, front view) and the rest display the banana in varying orientations (say, isometric views).

Comment: As far as I know there is no hyperparameter that can control the structure of a cnn model according to input dimension during training.

Comment: @Jugesh: Could you please put the first paragraph here in the comments?

Answer (score 2):

Almost always people will resize all their images to the same size before sending them to the CNN.  Unless you're up for a real challenge this is probably what you should do.

That said, it is *possible* to build a single CNN that takes input of images as varying dimensions.  There are a number of ways you might try to do this, and I'm not aware of any published science analyzing these different choices.  The key is that the set of learned parameters needs to be shared between the different inputs sizes.  While convolutions can be applied at different images sizes, ultimately they always get converted to a single vector to make predictions with, and the size of that vector will depend on the geometries of the inputs, convolutions and pooling layers.  You'd probably want to dynamically change the pooling layers based on the input geometry and leave the convolutions the same, since the convolutional layers have parameters and pooling usually doesn't.  So on bigger images you pool more aggressively.

Practically you'd want to group together similarly (identically) sized images together into minibatches for efficient processing.  This is common for LSTM type models.  This technique is commonly called "bucketing".  See for example http://mxnet.io/how_to/bucketing.html for a description of how to do this efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to create a network with layers that account for varying dimensions and orientations of the input image

The usual way to deal with different images is the following:

- You take one or multiple crops of the image to make `width = height`. If you take multiple crops, you pass all of them through the network and average the results.
- You scale the crop(s) to the size which is necessary for the network.

However, there is also Global Average Pooling (e.g. [Keras docs](https://keras.io/layers/pooling/#globalaveragepooling2d)).

> What is the necessary criteria of an eligible dataset to be used for training a Deep Network in general.

That is a difficult question to answer as (1) there are many different approaches in deep learning and the field is quite young (2) I'm pretty sure there is no quantitative answer right now.

Here are two rules of thumb:

- You should have at least 50 examples per class
- The more parameters your model has, the more data you need

[Learning curves](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_learning_curve.html) and [validation curves](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/learning_curve.html) help to estimate the effect of more training data.